# PHPUnit test and abstract class with a method named 'Method'

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I am in the process of testing an abstract class that has a method called `Method`.

Here is my abstract class (abridged):

```
abstract class ClassToTest {

  function Method($_value = NULL) {
    // based on the value passed in a different value is returned.
  }
}
```

Here is my PHPUnit class:

```
class ClassToTestTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
  public $object = NULL;

  public function setUp() {
    $this->object = $this->getMockForAbstractClass('ClassToTest');
  }

  public function testMethod() {

    // passing no value should return NULL
    $this->assertNull($this->object->Method());

    // passing a value should return a value
    $this->assertEquals($this->object->Method($method), 'return_value');
  }
}
```

Based on [PHPUnit Documentation](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.stubs) I should be able to use

```
$stub->expects($this->any())->method('Method')->willReturn('foo');
```

somehow, but I cannot figure out how to make this work.

How can I use PHPUnit to test a method called `Method`?

Also, I don't have the option to rename the method to something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Class you're testing is surely the only class you shouldn't be mocking. You wouldn't be really testing it if you faked its method calls.

Since your class is abstract you need to test it through a concrete implementation. If you don't have one, create it for the test.

```php
class MyClassToTest extends ClassToTest
{
    // implement abstract methods
}
```

```php
class ClassToTestTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    private $object;

    protected function setUp()
    {
        $this->object = new MyClassToTest();
    }

    public function testMethod()
    {
        $this->assertSame('return_value', $this->object->Method('foo'));
    }
```

}

Comment: There are a set of classes that inherit from this abstract class, so I can test it in that way but the method is declared and defined in the abstract class so it makes the most sense that the abstract class test should test the method and not rely on an inherited class to test it.

Comment: Use one of the implementations to test the abstract one. You could have a common test case class that all the implementation tests will inherit (as all of them will share this behaviour). Either way, mocking class under test is NOT the way.