# How to test a method called "method()" with PHPUnit's mock?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

Let's say I have a class looking like:

```
abstract class Foo
{
    private $method;

    public function method()
    {
        return $this->method;
    }
}
```

I want to test with PHPUnit:

```
$mock = $this->getMockForAbstractClass('Foo');
$this->assertEquals('...', $mock->method());
```

This does not work because `method()` is a reserved name for PHPUnit's mock objects.

How would one test a method with a name clashing with the mock interface?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHPUnit test and abstract class with a method named 'Method'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35306437/phpunit-test-and-abstract-class-with-a-method-named-method)

Answer (score 2):

You can send the method name in parameter like this:

```
$mock->method("method");
```

**EDIT**

You can refer to that example here:
https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html